# Bash script: Generate sha256sum hash and save its output with only filename, excluding path

Tags: bash, scripts

I like to write a Bash script to generate sha256sum hash of a file, and save its output with hash and only `filename.extension`, excluding the path.

I'm not getting the output I want with both of the following scripts I have tried so far:

Note: There will be a new file with a new name every time the script is run, hence I'm using `*.iso` in the script.

(1)

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/admn/Downloads

find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.iso" -exec bash -c "sha256sum '{}' > '{}'.sha256" \;

exit;
```

This creates a file `Test.iso.sha256` but with an output:
`e64d11052abf5c3e19f0cd60e0b9c6196d8cb8615eba415ef1a3ac746f4b0c29  ./Test.iso`

While I just want `Test.iso` without `./`

(2)

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/admn/Downloads

fullfilename="/home/admn/Downloads/*.iso"
filename=$(basename "$fullfilename")

sha256sum $filename > "$filename".sha256

exit;
```

This does generate the output I want: `e64d11052abf5c3e19f0cd60e0b9c6196d8cb8615eba415ef1a3ac746f4b0c29  Test.iso` but the file it creates have `*` in it instead of name: `*.iso.sha256`. Thanks.

OS: Ubuntu MATE 21.10

Bash: Version 5.1.8(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be sufficient to do

```
cd /home/admn/Downloads

for f in *.iso; do
  sha256sum "$f" > "$f.sha256"
done
```

Change `$f.sha256` to `${f%.iso}.sha256` if you want to remove the .iso extension before adding the sha256 extension.

Comment: it's perfect as I do want `name.iso.sha256`. Thank you so much as always.